# How to require SSL for all remote users

Tags: mysql, ssl, phpmyadmin

Given a MySQL system with multiple remote users (users of the form `'joecool'@'192.168.1.2'`); is there a SQL statement I can use to `REQUIRE SSL` for all the remote users?

The single user command is:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'joecool'@'192.168.1.2' REQUIRE SSL;
```

Having an "all user" version would be especially useful because [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) doesn't support the REQUIRE SSL flag when creating or modifying users.

Comment: I notice I can find people without the `REQUIRE SSL` via `SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE host like '192.168.%' AND ssl_type != 'ANY';` -- Can I modify the `mysql.user` table directly?

Comment: Note for today's visitors: phpMyAdmin has an SSL section at the bottom when creating or modifying users.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The (formerly) accepted answer by Honza seems incorrect, see its comments. It seems not possible to use a `GRANT` query to alter multiple users at once since [MySQL does not support wildcards for user names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-accounts-passwords).

As you suggested yourself you can alter records in the `mysql.user` table directly using an `UPDATE` query and as Marc Delisle suggested, afterwards flush priviliges with:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Also see [dba.stackexchange.com > How to grant multiple users privileges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27920/how-to-grant-multiple-users-privileges-mysql).

Answer (score 5):

You can configure `mysqld` with [require_secure_transport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_require_secure_transport).

```
[mysqld]
...
ssl-ca = ...
ssl-cert = ...
ssl-key = ...
...
require-secure-transport = ON
```

> This capability supplements per-account SSL requirements, which take
>   precedence. For example, if an account is defined with REQUIRE SSL,
>   enabling require_secure_transport does not make it possible to use the
>   account to connect using a Unix socket file.

Comment: This only works for mysql5.7, not supported on later or mariadb.

Comment: @JamesMV mysql8.0 supports that option as well: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_require_secure_transport

Comment: MariaDB added this in 10.5.2 - https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13362

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can modify the mysql.user table directly (be careful). Then you just issue a FLUSH PRIVILEGES statement to apply the changes to the running server.

Comment: The field which needs to be modified is `ssl_type`  of type  `enum('', 'ANY', 'X509', 'SPECIFIED')`. So to simulate `REQUIRE SSL` you would perform, `UPDATE mysql.user SET ssl_type='ANY' WHERE user='are you sure?'`. Note that seting this flag (to non-empty value), doesn't seem to have effect when connecting as `someuser@localhost`. (at least didn't block me from logging as `somuser@localhost`, but it DOES enforce SSL for  remote connections)

Comment: @DimitryK It probably doesn't affect localhost connections because those are most often (at least with the MySQL CLI) done using a UNIX socket (or a named pipe on Windows) and so TLS is unnecessary. I would imagine that if you tried connecting using `mysql -h 127.0.0.1` it would require SSL to be used.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, SSL **does** affect UNIX socket connections, so if you need high performance local transport you might be better off making sure ssl is disabled on your client. You can see SSL status with the `\s` command. Keep in mind SSL/TLS is only a layer on top of a streaming socket, so it can run on just any type of stream sockets. There could be use cases too, ex. using a socket proxy to a remote server.

Comment: @ThomasGuyot-Sionnest You are correct that TLS can be used over UNIX sockets (not TCP/IP sockets), but doing so would generally be silly. It's up to the client to decide whether TLS will be supported for the connection (and the server can refuse non-encrypted connections), but refusing a non-encrypted connection from `localhost` would be be equally silly.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, my point is that if you configure the MySQL client to use SSL, it will use it regardless of whenever you're connecting to a local socket or remote host.

Comment: Just a warning. According [to this][1] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_require_secure_transport)  *if an account is defined with REQUIRE SSL, enabling require_secure_transport does not make it possible to use the account to connect using a Unix socket file. *