# Require SSL on all MySql tables

Tags: mysql, security, ssl

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120856/how-to-require-ssl-for-all-remote-users) I know I can enable SSL connections on a per user basis.

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '%'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
```

How do I require SSL connections on a per table basis?  Is it possible?

```
// BAD SQL  
CREATE TABLE some_table REQUIRE SSL;
```

Comment: Well I think that SSL is used during connection. And you connect with a user. So I think it doesn't make sense to me to require SSL on a table. As documented there, it seems that I'm right : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ssl-connections.html - `MySQL enables encryption on a per-connection basis`

Comment: Consider making your `GRANT` statements more granular, and do it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @kmas above:

You don't.  You require SSL on the connection, not on the table.  So the proper way to require SSL is when granting user privileges.

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '%'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
```

And the wildcards are included for simplicity.  To be secure, it is probably best to specify exact values or at least ranges.

```
GRANT USAGE ON this_db.this_tbl TO 'joe'@'%.mydomain.com' REQUIRE SSL;
```

to allow access from all subdomains OR

```
GRANT USAGE ON this_db.this_tbl TO 'joe'@'xx.xx.xx.%' REQUIRE SSL;
```

to allow access from a range of IP addresses