# Why do I not need an SSL cert to connect to my database after running `REQUIRE SSL` statement?

Tags: mysql, ssl, heroku, amazon-rds

I have a Heroku app with a MySql database that we are migrating to a new RDS db instance.  I followed [this Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds) to configure SSL access to the new database.  I confirmed that my Heroku app can connect to the database with the new connection string, and that the ssl-ca query parameter is required to connect successfully.

However, I am able to connect to the database from my local terminal without any SSL cert, which is confusing me because my understanding is that all connections should require SSL. I had three other team members (including one off-site) connect to the database from their local terminals using the same username and password to confirm it wasn't something specific to my local machine. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120856/how-to-require-ssl-for-all-remote-users) I also tried running `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after running the `GRANT` statement to require SSL. I tried connecting to the database from MySQL Workbench and Sequel Pro, and wasn't able to connect without the SSL cert from either of those.

My question is, is there any reason that I should be able to connect to the RDS instance without including an SSL cert when SSL appears to be required when accessing the database from Heroku or from MySQL Workbench and Sequel Pro? Is it more likely that I haven't actually set SSL as required? Or is there some configuration quirk allowing me and others to connect from our terminals even though SSL is required?

For reference, here is what I get when I run `SHOW GRANTS` on the database for the user profile I'm using: 
`GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'beyond12'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*FFC9CC1968DAE51A82EE9BB70672D5F9D2BE957E' REQUIRE SSL WITH GRANT OPTION`

Comment: `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'SSL_CIPHER';` and what do you get?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot 
Ssl_cipher: AES256-SHA

Comment: Mystery solved.  Well, sort of.  You **are** connecting with SSL.  That value would be empty if you weren't.  The next question might be... what, in your local config, is enabling this?

Comment: `have_open_ssl` and `have_ssl` both values of `yes` when I run `show variables`.  I also have `ssl_cert`, `ssl_ca`, and `ssl_key` variable values that have PEM file locations.  I'm guessing all of these must have been brought over from the database I was originally restoring a snapshot of?

Comment: That's the server config.  RDS creates those automatically.  Your question (I thought) centers around not needing a cert/key/ca on the client side.

Comment: Correct, my question is about the local config.  I know I never explicitly provided the SSL cipher, so I'm curious when/how that would have got set

Comment: The cipher is automatically negotiated.  What client are you using? The `mysql` CLI?  Is there anything configured for SSL in the `[mysql]` or `[client]` section of your `my.cnf`?

Answer (score 0):

> This work for me in a RDS Postgres instance.

I haved same problem, my instance Postgres RDS allow connect without SSL cert, the looking for reason I find this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.Requiring) where they explain how to make Required SSL connection for all connections, as an resume they explain you have to change a **Parameter group** value named  **rds.force_ssl**, keep in mind before you can change this parameter value you to change your Parameter group, because you can't modify the default parameter group.