# How to enforce encrypted connections to Aurora RDS cluster w/ SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, rds, amazon-aurora

With PostgreSQL it looks like all you do is set rds.force_ssl to true in the parameter groups, but I don't see this as an option with Aurora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you would do this [in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120856/how-to-require-ssl-for-all-remote-users):

Run this command once for each MySQL user account you have, replacing `mysqluser` with the username:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
```

Then run this command to flush any cached privleges:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! Is 'awsmysql'@'%' just a placeholder you put in there, or is that like a catch all for any user that would be connecting to it? Thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry that's just a placeholder for the db user you created when you created the RDS instance. I think you need to run that `GRANT` command once for each DB user you have. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I just would like to confirm - there is no way to set this up on the db cluster level? Do I have to set this "REQUIRE SSL" parameter for the each user?